# How to print out matplotlib in VS Code

Tags: python, matplotlib

Just a small question.  I have VS Code installed and trying it out with Python but no matter what I try I cannot get matplotlib plots to appear.

Here is a simple code that does NOT work

```
import mglearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_wave(n_samples=40) 
plt.plot(X, y, 'o') 
plt.ylim(-3, 3) 
plt.xlabel("Feature") 
plt.ylabel("Target")
```

No error with the code appears but also no plot.  Thanks.

Please note mglearn comes from the following Github
https://github.com/amueller/mglearn

Comment: Did you mean VS Code instead of Visio, in the title and tags?

Comment: Looks like this has nothing to do with Microsoft Visio? I would also suggest you change the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `plt.show()` at the end.
And this additional line is just because the system asks me extra text for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.
You need to ask for the picture to be shown [plt.show()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) or to be saved [plt.savefig()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).

Just add `plt.show()` and you will obtain:

[image]

Comment: Thank you both for the answer...i tried to give both answers a check but not possible.  Thanks again.  Question resolved.